# Drop column from tuple list in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my tuple I guess

```
df = [(1.8799187420058687, 1), (1.5963945918878317, 2)]
```

The type of df shows up as this

```
print(type(df))
<type 'list'>
```

My goal is to remove the second variable column displayed as `1 and 2`

This is how I came up to the result (if that can help)

```
df = df.groupby('CBF_01').mean()
df = list(zip(df,df.index))
```

Expected output

```
df = (1.8799187420058687,1.5963945918878317)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

loop through each tuple, save the first value in a list and convert it to tuple.

```
new_df = tuple([x[0] for x in df])

output: (1.8799187420058687, 1.5963945918878317)
```

Comment: `tuple([x[0] for x in df])` .... I don't think you need to the `list(x)` you can access the first element of a tuple with indexing.

Comment: @ScottBoston you are right, I dint know that, Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Depending on how big the dataset is, you can loop through the dataframe and drop those, for example:

```
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    df['CBF_01'][i] = df['CBF_01'][i][0]
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer